# jQuery ajax - Absolute URL's and error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to catch the HTTP errors (like 404, 500, 504 etc) when we call an external webservice by specifying an absolute url?. (like setting the `url:` attribute of `$.ajax` call to have a url value as `http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes`.

Right now I'm unable to receive any errors although firebug is catching them and showing it in the console.

Can someone help?

Here is my code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes",
    data: '{"lat":47,"lng":"9","username":"demo"}',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache:false,
    async:false,
    statusCode:{
        404: function(){
            alert('Page not found');
        },
        500: function(){
            alert('Page not found');
        },
        504: function(){
            alert('Unknown host');
        }
    },
    success: function(data){
    alert(data);
         }
              error: function (xhr, exception, thrownError)
              {
                  alert(xhr.status);
              }
});
```

Comment: does the alert from your error block is being executed ?

Comment: you're missing a comma after the success callback

Comment: missing comma before error callback or bad copy/paste ?

Comment: Nico, soju Yeah.. It is a bad copy/paste

EvilP Nope. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible with cross-domain (external) requests using only client-side code.  This is because cross-domain requests rely on JSONP - ie, injecting a script tag that loads code from an external source.  Unfortunately, the `<script>` element does not have anything like an `onerror` event.

You can handle errors with same-domain requests because these typically use `XMLHttpRequest`, which returns a lot of useful information like status codes and response headers.

Your best bet would be to use your local server as a proxy.

Comment: Does that mean while using JSONP, we may not be able to have a error handler?

Comment: @david - Yes.  You cannot have an error handler for JSONP requests.

Answer (score 0):

If using an absolute URL causes the domain to be different from the domain of your page (cross-domain request), then the only way to successfully execute an ajax call is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which will cause the ajax library to use `<script>` tags for the cross-domain request instead of the more typical XMLHttpRequest used for same-domain requests.

You will not be able to intercept any sort of status codes from the loading of the cross-domain `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm able to see the appropriate errors in the firebug console?. Is there a way I can grab those and display them as alerts in my application?.

Comment: @DavidR - not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you cannot check the status code (assuming you're not making the request from api.geonames.org).

jQuery will always return a "0" as the status if the request is cross-domain:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://someotherdomain.com/api/query',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: '{"first": 1, "second": 2}',
    complete: function(response) {    // the 'response' object has the status code
        if (response.status == '200') {
            // do something on success
        } else if (response.status == '0') {
            alert('Your request is cross-domain');
        }
    }
});
```

If the request happens to be within the same domain, you'll get a valid status code that you can check (the `complete` attribute of the `$.ajax()` function will run after any `success` or `failure` callbacks are run).

Comment: Thanks Joe!.. But I'm able to see the appropriate errors in the firebug console?. Is there a way I can grab those and display them as alerts in my application?.

Comment: @DavidR Yes, I'm pretty sure the status code in Firebug is completely separate from the status code you'll be receiving programmatically via AJAX (as a few examples show from doing a quick Google search).

Comment: Your best bet for a workaround is using JSONP, although that does have a few restrictions (as @gilly3 noted). I would go with access from the server-side on the local domain, and then use AJAX to pull the results properly to the client-side.